# Typescript - unexpected control character(s) in regular expression that contains ESC character

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following nodejs/typescript code:

```
const re = /\x1b\[.*?m/gi;
message.replace(re, '');   // message = '[32m"Hello"[39m' // the string contains ESC charater at start and end.
```

eslint throws an error `Unexpected control character(s) in regular expression: \x1b  no-control-regex`. What am i doing wrong in the regex? Expecting the output to be `"Hello"`.

Comment: Did you read https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-control-regex?